# Android Software Decoder (OMX.google.h264.decoder) Fails to decode H264 video

Tags: android, video, h.264, android-mediacodec

I am experiencing issues when trying to extract and decode H264 video using Androids software decoder (OMX.google.h264.decoder). The issue seems to span multiple devices.

This video does playback fine using a Nexus 5 hardware decoder (OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc).

The sample code below exhibits the issue and is a fairly standard example of using the android MediaCodec and MediaExtractor classes.

The exception I get is an illegal state exception when the first buffer is passed to the decoder.

The video is 720x480 20fps encoded at the Baseline profile so should meet compatibility guidelines.

[Here is a video sample to accompany the code](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E532F98F64CDBE0A!237&authkey=!ADZJsvULUUZAHrI&ithint=file%2Cmp4)

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on getting the software video decoder correctly working with H264 video.

```
public void doMp4Test()
{
    try
    {
        //String filename = "webserver_h264.mp4";
        String filename = "toodee-720p.mp4";
        MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
        extractor.setDataSource(Constants.RootDirectory + File.separator + filename); 

        MediaCodec decoder = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < extractor.getTrackCount(); i++)
        {
            MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
            String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
            if (mime.startsWith("video/"))
            {
                extractor.selectTrack(i);
                decoder = MediaCodec.createByCodecName("OMX.google.h264.decoder");
                // decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc"); // working decoder type
                decoder.configure(format, m_surface, null, 0);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (decoder == null)
        {
            Log.e("DecodeActivity", "Can't find video info!");
            return;
        }

        decoder.start();

        ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
        ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
        BufferInfo info = new BufferInfo();
        boolean isEOS = false;
        long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (!Thread.interrupted())
        {
            if (!isEOS)
            {
                int inIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);
                if (inIndex >= 0)
                {
                    ByteBuffer buffer = inputBuffers[inIndex];
                    int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(buffer, 0);
                    if (sampleSize < 0)
                    {
                        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "InputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                        decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                        isEOS = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int flags = 0;// extractor.getSampleFlags();
                        decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, sampleSize, extractor.getSampleTime(), flags);
                        extractor.advance();
                    }
                }
            }

            int outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 10000);
            switch (outIndex)
            {
            case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
                Log.d("DecodeActivity", "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
                outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
                break;
            case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
                Log.d("DecodeActivity", "New format " + decoder.getOutputFormat());
                break;
            case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
                Log.d("DecodeActivity", "dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!");
                break;
            default:
                ByteBuffer buffer = outputBuffers[outIndex];
                Log.v("DecodeActivity", "We can't use this buffer but render it due to the API limit, " + buffer);

                // We use a very simple clock to keep the video FPS, or the
                // video
                // playback will be too fast
                while (info.presentationTimeUs / 1000 > System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true);
                break;
            }

            if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0)
            {
                Log.d("DecodeActivity", "OutputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                break;
            }
        }

          decoder.stop();
          decoder.release();
          extractor.release();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Tested about half a dozen H.264 videos.  This Google decoder works with only one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the video with ffprobe it looks like it is actually high profile rather than base profile:

> Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 515 kb/s, 24.66 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 2000k tbc (default)

As an aside, the video seems to play but just display a black blank screen when playing back on a couple of browsers when I just tried it on a laptop.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I have tried changing the format to baseline in our Intel encoder but it still will not play. I imagine that there are a lot of other settings that may be breaking compatibility. Do you have access to a example .mp4 or .h264 file that would be compatible and work with the above code? It would hep me greatly in configuring the encoder correctly.

Comment: @MichaelDavidKnight This link has an h.264 mp4 video that should work - I just tested it on Android 4.2 and it played back with the Android browser and the chrome browser: http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/video.html